# R, fread CSV - how to maintain line breaks in cell values?

Tags: r, fread

I've got a CSV file that I am reading into an R script using `fread`. The resulting variable is a vector, which is what I need for the next step in my process. There are values in my CSV file such as `'Energy \nElectricity'`, and the intention is that these will be labels for a chart, with a line break between (in this case) `'Energy'` and `'Electricity'` for formatting reasons.

When I manually code the vector to be
`myVec <- c('Energy \nElectricity')`, this works fine and the line break is maintained.
When I read the data in using `fread`, however, the resulting vector is effectively `c('Energy \\nElectricity')`, i.e. the process has inserted an extra escape character and the formatting is lost.

My question is as follows:

1. Is there a way to use `fread` to maintain these line breaks at all?
2. If not, can I format them differently in my csv file?
3. If not, can I use `gsub` or similar to remove the extra line break once the file has been read into a vector?

I have tried all manner of ways to implement `gsub` (and `sub`), but they either get rid of both escape characters, such as `gsub("\\\\", "\\", myVec)` which gives 
`[1] "Energy nElectricity"`, or they throw an error. I think I am missing something obvious. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `cat(gsub('\\\\n','\n','Energy \\nElectricity'))`

Comment: this gives me the correct format, but I need to keep the vector c('Energy \nElectricity') in a variable, in this case, to pass to a plotting function. `cat` doesn't allow me to do this, I believe; when I define `btest <- cat(gsub('\\\\n', '\n', myVec))`, `btest` is NULL.

Comment: Uh, ok ... `vec <- gsub('\\\\n','\n','Energy \\nElectricity')` ... ?

Comment: Yes, this also works, thank you. I clearly didn't have enough or too many backslashes in mine when I tried various iterations of this... but I have accepted the below answer as it's easier to read (and apparently faster, although I haven't tested this).

Comment: You weren't missing a backslash, you were missing the `n`s. No worries, glad you got it to work. I agree that `fixed=TRUE` is probably faster, though you are unlikely to really see any difference (or care about it) unless you are dealing with 5-6 digit length vectors and/or really long strings. For example, I just benchmarked a vector 1e5 long, and though `fixed=FALSE` took twice as long as `fixed=TRUE`, it was in the milliseconds, not huge.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to know that it does make a difference, even if only a tiny bit. In my case they're records with less than ten items so it would have no impact at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nobody comes up with a better solution, this is how you would clean it using gsub:

```
gsub("\\n", "\n", "Energy \\nElectricity", fixed = TRUE)
```

The `fixed` option ignores all regex characters and is also considerably faster than `fixed = FALSE`.

Comment: Given the very few data points I have in this case, I think this is a very suitable solution. Thank you.

Comment: using stringi might be faster but this is probably good enough

Comment: I think the difference between `gsub()` with option `fixed = TRUE` and stringi's `stri_replace_all_fixed()` is negligible. As far as I remember from testing this a while back stringi's big advantage is with regex.